# can't understand type aliases and const

Tags: c++, types, alias

i'm here because i need of help with type aliases and const.
i'm a real beginner in c++ and i'm studying from the book " c++ primer ".
my problem is that i can't understand why :

```
int ival = 10; 
const int *p = &ival; // this is a pointer to const 

int rval = 15; 
int *const ppi = &rval; // this is a const pointer

typedef int *integer; // if i create an alias for the type int 


int num = 50; 
const integer pr = &num; // this is not a pointer to const but a pointer to const 

// so my book is telling me that this : const int *pr = &num; is a wrong interpretation
```

can someone explain me why this ? i've studied pointer ( the basics ) and i can't       undestand this

Comment: *this is not a pointer to const but a pointer to const* - That's a real helpful comment. Anyway, the type alias is a full packaged type. You can't add `const` to any level but the top.

Comment: `integer` is not an alias for type `int` but type `int *`. `const integer` is equivilent to `int *const` and not `const int *`. Just the rulz I'm afraid.

Comment: Just think of all the `const T` generic code that would be broken as a result of this when `const int` is perfectly fine and equivalent to `int const`.

Comment: `const` binds to the thing that is before it. The exception is when `const` appears first, in which case it binds to the thing after it.

Comment: `// this is not a pointer to const but a pointer to const` wait what ?

Comment: yes but i can't understand why my book doesn't explain me that when const appears first it binds to the thing after

Comment: Because books on C++ are often wrong.

Comment: yes sometimes this book is awesome some times not, c++ primer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the const to the right side, it would be easier to read. You do it from right to left.

```
const int *p = &ival;
```

This is equivalent to

```
int const *p = &ival.
```

You read it "pointer to const int". Pointer is not const, data it points to is const.

```
int * const ppi = &rval;
```

Here the const is already on the right side and you read "const pointer to int". The pointer is const, the data it points to is not const.

```
typedef int *integer;
int num = 50; 
const integer pr = &num;
```

In this case you have

```
integer const pr = &num;
```

What is basically, if you replace `integer` with `int*`:

```
int* const pr = &num;
```

And that is read "const pointer to int", just like in the second case.

Comment: +1 *You should put the const to the right side* -- sane advice